# centos pentaho bi server issues

Tags: centos, pentaho

This question is regarding pentaho suite's `server` component, not PDI.

I succesfully "installed" and run the server on my windows box, but I'm having the hardest time deploying it on a centos box.

Server info, and what I've tried so far:

```
#cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

#wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie:oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" 
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.rpm
#rpm -ivh jdk-8u131-linux-x64.rpm
#java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

#cat /root/.bashrc  #I know: whenever it runs as root, I'll change the user it runs under
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre

#/home/XXX/pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Yet, If I `netstat -antlp` I see no process listening on port 8080.

So, I went to tomcat log files:

```
#ls -lah /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/logs
total 120K
drwxrwxrwx  2 XXX XXX 4.0K Oct 30 21:23 .
drwxrwxrwx 10 XXX XXX 4.0K Sep  7 16:51 ..
-rw-r-----  1 XXX XXX 52K Oct 30 22:07 catalina.2020-10-30.log
-rw-r-----  1 XXX XXX 52K Oct 30 22:07 catalina.out
-rw-r-----  1 XXX XXX 0 Oct 30 20:47 host-manager.2020-10-30.log
-rw-r-----  1 XXX XXX 0 Oct 30 20:47 localhost.2020-10-30.log
-rw-r-----  1 XXX XXX 0 Oct 30 20:47 localhost_access_log.2020-10-30.txt
-rw-r-----  1 XXX XXX 0 Oct 30 20:47 manager.2020-10-30.log

#cat /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2020 22:26:25 UTC
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.51.0
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-042stab141.3
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.021 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.021 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.021 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.021 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.022 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.023 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.024 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.025 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.025 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.025 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.027 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms2048m
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.027 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx6144m
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=utf8
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.029 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DDI_HOME=/home/XXX/pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/kettle
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.031 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/temp
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.031 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.438 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.472 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1414 ms
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.616 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.639 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/XXX/pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho]
30-Oct-2020 22:07:57.757 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'docbase' to 'webapps/pentaho/' did not find a matching property.
```

The only things that catches my attention is the last line, that seems to me (far from an expert at reading tomcat logs) that might be an stop log.

I'm out of ideas, I don't know how to debug any further.

Any suggestions will be MUCH appreciated!

Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here after a similar error:

Check your `dmesg`: I was trying to run tomcat service with too much RAM memory.